# How to covert a Java collection into a Kotlin Sequence (and vice versa) in Java?

Tags: java, collections, kotlin, sequence

I am implementing a Kotlin interface in Java which expects me to return a `Sequence<T>`.

How can I convert a Java collection into a Kotlin `Sequence`? Conversely, how can I convert a Kotlin `Sequence` into a Java collection?

Answer (score 1):

Here are some conversions:

```
val javaList = java.util.ArrayList<String>()
javaList.addAll(listOf("A", "B", "C"))

// From Java List to Sequence
val seq = sequenceOf(*javaList.toTypedArray())
// or
val seq2 = javaList.asSequence()

// Sequence to Kotlin List
val list = seq.toList()

// Kotlin List to Sequence
val seqFromList = sequenceOf(*list.toTypedArray())
// or
val seqFromList2 = list.asSequence()

// Sequence to Java List
val newJavaList = java.util.ArrayList<String>().apply { seqFromList.toCollection(this) }
// or
val newJavaList2 = java.util.ArrayList<String>()
newJavaList2.addAll(seqFromList)
```

Comment: Hi @DVarga, There is no  asSequnece method in any of the Java collection.  I could not find asSequence method in  ArrayList

Comment: [`asSequence`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/as-sequence.html) is an extension function in [`kotlin.collections`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/index.html).

Comment: Yes, but I have to implement Kotlin interface in java which returns Sequence<T>...... I have the Java collection ArrayList<?> but how do I convert it into Sequence bcz Java collections don't have the .asSequence method

Answer (score 1):

Since the Kotlin code gets run from Java, it gets a bit trickier.

Let's try to recreate the scenario:

Kotlin:

```
interface SequenceInterface {
    fun foo(list: List<Int>) : Sequence<Int>
}
```

If you inspect Kotlin code, you will discover that there's no particular implementation of the `Sequence` interface. So, in your case, you need to implement it by yourself (just like Kotlin is doing when calling `asSequence`:

```
public class Foo implements SequenceInterface {
    @NotNull
    public Sequence<Integer> foo(final List<Integer> list) {
        return () -> list.listIterator();
    }
}
```

and then you can start using it in Java:

```
new Foo().foo(Arrays.asList(42))
```

Keep in mind that all useful methods will be gone since they are implemented as Kotlin extensions.

Want to convert to `List`? In plain Java, just reiterate:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
seq.iterator().forEachRemaining(list::add);
```

---

Also, make sure that you absolutely need to return a `Sequence` in Kotlin's code. If you want to achieve better interoperability, returning a `Stream` would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
val javaList = java.util.ArrayList<String>()
val kotlinSeq = javaList.asSequence()
val newJavaList = java.util.ArrayList<String>().apply { kotlinSeq.toCollection(this) }
```